# What's the issue in this code?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the year in which the user was born. This is my current code:

```
puts "We're in 2016"
puts "How old are you"
in1 = gets.chomp
in2 = 2016
out = (in2 - in1)
print out
gets()
```

I'm trying to do this like in Python. Can someone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: For a start...Ruby isn't Python...also, you're subtracting a total age from the current *year* which is never going to be correct.  I'm very confused as to what it is you're attempting to accomplish since you're *asking* the user's age to begin with!  Did you mean to ask them what year they were born in instead?

Comment: What's Phyton? Never heard of it

Comment: @Makoto That's it, I explained bad in fact, I'm spanish. I wanted to substract the user's age to the current year to get when was he/she born. But it closes so fast that I don't have time to read the message.

Answer (score 1):

For the correct code, this is how it should be. Whether this is the result you want is another matter.

```
 puts "We're in 2016"
 puts "How old are you"
 in1 = gets.chomp
 in2 = 2016
 out = (in2 - in1.to_i)
 print out
```

For starters, if you want to learn python then just go ahead and learn python. Ruby like other languages have their own way of doing things so writing Ruby in a Python like way just doesn't make sense at all. For returning the age of a user all you need to do is this:

```
puts "We're in 2016"
puts "How old are you"
in1 = gets.chomp
print in1
```

Comment: thanks man, that helped but, what does .to_i method do?

Comment: No problem, the .to_i means "to integer" I am changing your string into an integer so you can subtract values. Check out this documentation and for all other ruby related stuff. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html

Comment: Thanks again, that helped. Maybe for future programs. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "We're in 2016"
puts "How old are you" 
in1 = gets.chomp.to_i
in2 = 2016 
out = (in2 - in1) 
puts out
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  You want `gets.chomp.to_i`.

Comment: When answering, please explain why the code is useful and why it fixes the problem. The goal is to help the person asking to understand so they don't make the same mistakes in the future.